# Asterisk connect to a parked call

Tags: asterisk, phone-call, amazon-ami, agi

I am developing a custom application to control an Asterisk based pbx using ami/agi interface. What I have to do is:

1. receive a call from a pstn external line
2. answer the call
3. play a welcome message
4. transfer the call to a specific extension
5. park the call
6. reconnect to the call from a different extension

Everything should be done using ami/agi interfaces. I succesfully developed everything up to point 5) but I am unable to understand how to transfer (using ami/agi) the parked call to a runtime-defined extension.

Can someone give me an idea on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

you should originate from Local/XXX@parked_context to the extension you want.

something like this..

- Action: Originate Channel: Local/XXX@parked_context (XXX is the number of parked call)
- Context: default (here you put the context    where you can reach the second party)
- Exten: 123 (number who will receive the call)
- Priority: 1
- Callerid: 3125551212
- Timeout: 30000
- Variable:
- ActionID:

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just use async agi or conference or Wait extension instead of parking, i.e redo parking-like logic yourself.

That way you will 100% know channel name and how to transfer it back.

Considering you are gooing use ami - AsyncAGI is best option for you.